# vscode go linter linting go code, how to disable

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I am using go in vscode.  The problem is that it seems to be linting the golang source code and is coming up with warnings.  How do I disable the linting of the go source code itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of recommendation:

- Update everything (VScode, Go, VSCode-Go extension)
- Make sure your workspace (or opened folder) is limited to your project sources.
- Use golangci-lint as Lit Tool
- Activate the "Go: Lint on save" setting, with 'package' as the selected option.

Comment: thnaks VonC, but I have already done this and it did not work.

Comment: @tmpdev Can you try, for testing, with a new Go project (same module name, just one `main.go` file) and see if the issue persists there. If it does not, add back your source files of your current project in this new one.